# How to decompress a ZIP file with specified file/directory name character encoding?

Tags: zip, encoding

I got ZIP file(s), which contains files, which filenames are in some encoding. Let's say I know encoding of those filenames, but I still dont know how to properly decompress them.

Here is example [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4444564/stackoverflow/gb18030.zip), it contains one file 
"【SSK字幕组】The Vampire Diaries 吸血鬼日记S06E12.ass"

I know used encoding is GB18030 (Chinese)

Question is - how to unpack that file in FreeBSD using unzip or other CLI utility to get proper encoded filename? I tried everything what I could, but result was never good. Please help.

I tried on OSX:

```
MBP1:test 2ge$ bsdtar xf gb18030.zip
MBP1:test 2ge$ ls
%A1%BESSK%D7%D6Ļ%D7顿The Vampire Diaries %CE%FCѪ%B9%ED%C8ռ%C7S06E12/      gb18030.zip
MBP1:test 2ge$ cd %A1%BESSK%D7%D6Ļ%D7顿The\ Vampire\ Diaries\ %CE%FCѪ%B9%ED%C8ռ%C7S06E12/
MBP1:%A1%BESSK%D7%D6Ļ%D7顿The Vampire Diaries %CE%FCѪ%B9%ED%C8ռ%C7S06E12 2ge$ ls
%A1%BESSK%D7%D6Ļ%D7顿The Vampire Diaries %CE%FCѪ%B9%ED%C8ռ%C7S06E12.ass*
MBP1:%A1%BESSK%D7%D6Ļ%D7顿The Vampire Diaries %CE%FCѪ%B9%ED%C8ռ%C7S06E12 2ge$ find . | iconv -f gb18030 -t utf-8
.
./%A1%BESSK%D7%D6L抬%D7椤縏he Vampire Diaries %CE%FC血%B9%ED%C8占%C7S06E12.ass 
MBP1:%A1%BESSK%D7%D6Ļ%D7顿The Vampire Diaries %CE%FCѪ%B9%ED%C8ռ%C7S06E12 2ge$ convmv -r -f gb18030 -t utf-8 --notest .
Skipping, already UTF-8: ./%A1%BESSK%D7%D6Ļ%D7顿The Vampire Diaries %CE%FCѪ%B9%ED%C8ռ%C7S06E12.ass
Ready!
```

I tried similar with unzip, but I get similar problem.

Thanks, now trying on FREE BSD, where I am connecting using SSH from OSX (Terminal):

```
# locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

The first thing, I would like to is to proper show Chinese names. I changed

```
setenv LC_ALL zh_CN.GB18030
setenv LANG zh_CN.GB18030
```

Then I downloaded [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4444564/stackoverflow/%E3%80%90SSK%E5%AD%97%E5%B9%95%E7%BB%84%E3%80%91The%20Vampire%20Diaries%20%E5%90%B8%E8%A1%80%E9%AC%BC%E6%97%A5%E8%AE%B0S06E12/%E3%80%90SSK%E5%AD%97%E5%B9%95%E7%BB%84%E3%80%91The%20Vampire%20Diaries%20%E5%90%B8%E8%A1%80%E9%AC%BC%E6%97%A5%E8%AE%B0S06E12.ass) and try to "ls" to see proper characters, but not luck. So I think I have to solve first Chinese locale to verify when I get proper result, actually I can compare it. Can you also help me please with this?

Answer (score 35):

Here's what I do on Ubuntu 16.04 to unzip a zip in any encoding, as long as I know what that encoding is. The same method should work on FreeBSD because it only relies on widely available `unzip` tool.

1. I double-check the exact name of the encoding, as to not misspell it: https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml
2. I simply run

   ```
   $ unzip -O <encoding> <filename> -d <target_dir>
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ unzip -I <encoding> <filename> -d <target_dir>
   ```

   choosing between `-O` or `-I` according to instructions here:

   ```
   $ unzip -h
   UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.
     ...
     -O CHARSET  specify a character encoding for DOS, Windows and OS/2 archives
     -I CHARSET  specify a character encoding for UNIX and other archives
     ...
   ```

   which means that I simply try `-O` and it should work, because not a lot of people would create a `.zip` file in Unix...

---

So, for your specific example:

1. The exact encoding name is `GB18030`.
2. I use the `-O` flag and:

   ```
   $ unzip -O GB18030 gb18030.zip -d target_dir
   Archive:  gb18030.zip
      creating: target_dir/【SSK字幕组】The Vampire Diaries 吸血鬼日记S06E12/
     inflating: target_dir/【SSK字幕组】The Vampire Diaries 吸血鬼日记S06E12/【SSK字幕组】The Vampire Diaries 吸血鬼日记S06E12.ass
   ```

   ... it works.

Comment: For zips created by Greek Windows I had success with this method and encoding CP737

Comment: Bravo! I double checked the man page, it actually *works* but totally undocumented, none the zsh completion have this parameter.

Comment: `unzip` does not have this option in Mac OS X and always creates percent-encoded filenames. @javacom's `unar` suggestion worked as a charm.

Comment: Looks like a Debian-specific functionality. My `unzip` tells it's `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler` and doesn't provide such options.

Comment: @L29Ah My `unzip` in Debian 9 is exactly the same version and has no such options. Probably Ubuntu specific?

Comment: @Arnie97 and L29Ah: The unzip on CentOS 7.6.1810 (not Debian family) reports itself as `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.` and it has these options.

Comment: why this is not accepted answer?

Comment: You can use `-O` option on any distributions. First, download the source by `apt source unzip` on Ubuntu (live environment is enough). Second, copy the `unzip-6.0` directory to your system. Third, `cd` into the directory. Finally, execute `sudo make --file=unix/Makefile generic && sudo make --file=unix/Makefile install` to compile and install. The default `prefix` is `/usr/local` (not just `/usr`). For the detailed explanation, read `README` and `INSTALL`. This procedure is confirmed on Arch Linux, whose original `unzip` doesn't supply `-O` option.

Comment: @ynn Or you can pick only `unzip-6.0/debian/patches/20-unzip60-alt-iconv-utf8.patch` and apply it to an official source by [Info-ZIP](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/UnZip.html) and then compile and install. This procedure is also confirmed on Arch Linux. (On Arch, you can `asp checkout unzip` and then `makepkg -o` and then apply the patch and then `makepkg -ei`.)

Comment: `unzip -O utf-8 archive.zip` worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 33):

**Method 1** : use unar utility

```
sudo apt-get install unar

unar -e gb18030 gb18030.zip
```

**Method 2** : Use a python script to unzip the file (reference https://gist.github.com/usunyu/dfc6e56af6e6caab8018bef4c3f3d452#file-gbk-unzip-py )

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# unzip-gbk.py

import os
import sys
import zipfile
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--encoding", help="encoding for filename, default gbk")
parser.add_argument("-l", help="list filenames in zipfile, do not unzip", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("file", help="process file.zip")
args = parser.parse_args()
print "Processing File " + args.file

file=zipfile.ZipFile(args.file,"r");
if args.encoding:
    print "Encoding " + args.encoding
for name in file.namelist():
    if args.encoding:
        utf8name=name.decode(args.encoding)
    else:
        utf8name=name.decode('gbk')
    pathname = os.path.dirname(utf8name)
    if args.l:
        print "Filename " + utf8name
    else:
        print "Extracting " + utf8name
        if not os.path.exists(pathname) and pathname!= "":
            os.makedirs(pathname)
        data = file.read(name)
        if not os.path.exists(utf8name):
            fo = open(utf8name, "w")
            fo.write(data)
            fo.close
file.close()
```

The example gb18030.zip will extract the following file

```
【SSK字幕组】The Vampire Diaries 吸血鬼日记S06E12
【SSK字幕组】The Vampire Diaries 吸血鬼日记S06E12/【SSK字幕组】The Vampire Diaries 吸血鬼日记S06E12.ass
```

Comment: Thank you, the `unar` method is the most hassle-free at least on Mac OS X.

Comment: `unar` will guess the encoding if you don't provide one. Nice tool.

Answer (score 13):

On most POSIX filesystems the filename is just a series of bytes and it's up to userspace to make any sense of it. You can use this to your advantage.

1. First, extract the archive using `bsdtar`, since the `unzip` tool seems to mangle the file names, while bsdtar will extract them raw. (I'm testing this on Linux. I guess FreeBSD just calls it `tar`.)

   ```
   $ bsdtar xf gb18030.zip
   ```
2. Verify that tools like `iconv` can successfully decode the names:

   ```
   $ find . | iconv -f gb18030 -t utf-8
   ```

   (Note that this only affects the `find` output, not files themselves.)
3. Finally use `convmv` to convert the file names to UTF-8:

   ```
   $ convmv -r -f gb18030 -t utf-8 --notest .
   ```

   (Note: I had to install Encode::HanExtra from CPAN for the GB18030 support, *and* manually add `use Encode::HanExtra;` to  /usr/bin/convmv even though it's supposed to
4. In case `convmv` is unavailable, script it:

   ```
   $ find . -depth | while read -r old; do
       old=./$old;
       head=${old%/*};
       tail=${old##*/};
       new=$head/$(echo "$tail" | iconv -f gb18030 -t utf-8);
       [ "$old" = "$new" ] || mv "$old" "$new";
   done
   ```

   (At least on Linux, this has an advantage in that `iconv` is almost always available, and it *always* supports gb18030.)

Comment: thanks grawity looking into this. I am testing right now on OSX (but thats really close to FreeBSD, and I think result will be similar). adding comment to my question, can not edit here...

Comment: @2ge: Ah, OSX might actually be quite different, as HFS+ internally forces file names into NFD UTF-16 rather than storing bytestrings, so there's a possibility that it'll corrupt the GB18030 names before you get a chance to convert them.

Comment: I edited original question, add some more comments.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it on macOS Sierra and bsdtar reported lots of "Failed to create xxx" errors (because the parent directory names are corrput). Had to copy my archive to a Linux VPS, use unzip -O to extract it, and copy the result back to my Mac using ssh -C.

Answer (score 7):

On OS X, you can use a GUI application called [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com). It can be installed using [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353) or [Homebrew Cask](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/the-unarchiver):

```
brew cask install the-unarchiver
```

When you open a ZIP file with it, the application lets you choose the appropriate encoding using preview of a filename from the archive.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

7z supports charset ID with a switch `-scs`, e.g.:

```
7z x -scs903 some.zip
```

where 903 is 中文簡體 charset. A longer list of charset IDs can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180423031654/http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/ccsid/ccsid_registered.html).

Comment: `7z` `-scs` switch chooses only the encoding of the `@`-defined file list.

Comment: Acoording to [documen](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/charset.htm), it works on `add` and `update` only... I tried with extract but in vain. My current way in windows is using ubuntu in wsl2 to unzip a legacy encoding zip...

Answer (score 2):

unar never turn me down:

```
brew install unar

unar -e GBK *.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used 7zip and it managed to pick the right encoding –
something that standard zip couldn't do.

However, I used it on Windows, with the GUI tool.  Maybe the command line `7z` will work for you, too.

Comment: Yes, there is ***now*** another answer recommending 7z.  You can hardly expect Berry’s answer to “add more” to an answer that was posted almost five months later.

Comment: @Scott My apologies, I failed to read the English month abbreviations correctly.

Comment: OK. You might want to know that, if you put your mouse pointer over any date on the page (and “hover” there), it will show you the date as numbers. (At least this works on computers; people say it doesn’t work well on phones.) Also, below the bottom right corner of the question, you will see “active  oldest  votes”. This is answer sort order. If you click on “oldest”, then you will get the answers in order from oldest to newest.

Answer (score 1):

Use 7z to extract the file

```
7z x yourfile.zip
```

After that, convert the encoding of those filenames yourself:

```
convmv --notest -f from_encoding -t utf-8 -r your_extracted_folder/
```

This works for me.. from_encoding in my case is tis-620 (which is a Thai encoding), you need to find an appropriate encoding of your language. A popular one usually solves the problem but if the file name is still unreadable then try  changing from_encoding to other things such as windows-1252 or shift-jis (Japanese) or whatever, you can list the available encoding using command:

```
convmv --list
iconv --list
```

This is very simple "how to solve" method for me.

Answer (score 0):

Shell `sh` oneline script with `iconv`:

```sh
for f in /path/*.txt; do mv $f `echo $f | iconv -f 866 -t UTF-8`; done
```

Script above is loop doing iterate through whilecard and move files from one codepage (866) to another (utf8).

Same and with reading while-card from pipe line:

```sh
echo * | for f in `read f&&echo $f`; do mv $f `echo $f | iconv -f 866 -t UTF-8`; done
```

There is no output except access rights denied if any.
Also warning is possible when filename is the same in both codepage, because it appears as move file to same path.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation of what your script is doing, and maybe a possible output of what may be the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a patch for unzip fixing this issue:
https://sourceforge.net/p/infozip/patches/29/

The same patch for p7zip:
https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/bugs/187/

Answer (score 0):

python3 script to unpack cp866 archive:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import sys

def extract(filepath, directory = '', listonly = False):
  with ZipFile(filepath, 'r') as zip:
    for name in zip.namelist():
      data = zip.read(name)
      unicode_name = name.encode('cp437').decode('cp866')
      type = "DIR" if zip.getinfo(name).is_dir() else "FILE"

      print(type, unicode_name)
      if listonly:
        continue
      if zip.getinfo(name).is_dir():
        continue

      unicode_name = directory + '/' + unicode_name
      dirpath = os.path.dirname(unicode_name)
      if not os.path.exists(dirpath):
        os.makedirs(dirpath)
      f = open(unicode_name, 'wb')
      f.write(data)
  return 0

kwargs = {}
i = 1
while i < len(sys.argv):
  arg = sys.argv[i]
  if arg[0] != '-':
    kwargs['filepath'] = arg
  elif arg == '-l':
    kwargs['listonly'] = True
  elif arg == '-h':
    kwargs['usage'] = True
  elif arg == '-d':
    i += 1
    kwargs['directory'] = sys.argv[i]
  i += 1

argc = len(kwargs)
if argc > 3:
  print("Error: Max. 3 args expected,", argc, "are given.")
  exit(1)

print("Arguments given:", kwargs)

if "usage" in kwargs:
  print("""
Usage: %s [OPTIONS] FILEPATH")
Options:
  -l - list files only
  -d - output directory
""" % sys.argv[0])
  exit(1)

ret = extract(**kwargs)
exit(ret)
```

Example:

```
❯ ./unzip Budget_2020.zip -d dir
Arguments given: {'filepath': 'Budget_2020.zip', 'directory': 'dir'}
FILE Исполнение бюджета 2020 г/Исполнение бюджета 2020 года.pdf
DIR Исполнение бюджета 2020 г/Приложения к Заключению/
FILE Исполнение бюджета 2020 г/Приложения к Заключению/01_Прил_к Заключению Доходы.xls
FILE Исполнение бюджета 2020 г/Приложения к Заключению/02_Прил_к Заключению ГП.xlsx
FILE Исполнение бюджета 2020 г/Приложения к Заключению/03_Прил_к Заключению ГП ГРБС.xlsx
FILE Исполнение бюджета 2020 г/Приложения к Заключению/04_Прил_к Заключению ГП ИНД.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

With 7zip, You can specify the encoding to use with the `-mcp` switch.

To extract simplified Chinese zip files with GB18030 encoding (Code page 54936)

```
7z e -mcp=54946 zipname.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

If the zip archive is created with non unicode codec, you can specify the character encoding as `unzip -O <encoding> <filename> -d <target_dir>`, see @Melebius's answer.

But if a zip file is created with a non unicode codec and also encrypted with a password including non ascii characters, the password you pass to `unzip` command also needs to be encoded as bytes in this codec. On Linux, the argument you pass to `unzip` will be read as `utf-8`, so if it has a password like `吸血鬼日记`, this won't work: `unzip -O GB18030 -P '吸血鬼日记' compressed.zip`.

So you need a way to provide password encoded in `GB18030` as bytes to unzip. There's no simple way to do this with `unzip` command , but this can be done with a Python script:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile


def extract_zip(archive_name, out_path, pwd, codec):
    # password also needs to be encoded with codec
    password = pwd.encode(codec) if pwd else None
    # metadata_encoding argument is available in Python3.11
    with ZipFile(archive_name, "r", metadata_encoding=codec) as myzip:
        myzip.extractall(out_path, pwd=password)


extract_zip("compressed.zip", "output_dir", "吸血鬼日记", "GB18030")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [PeaZip](https://peazip.github.io/):

Open the archive, and then select Options -> ZIP Filenames Encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Since unzip is mangling the encoding of non-ascii file, the simplest workaround, as mentioned in other answers, is to switch to `7z` and specifically to `7za` which worked as expected on mac:

```bsh
7za x '*.zip'
```

> Note the use of quotes — this prevents expansion by the shell (bash, zsh, etc) and delegates the expansion to `7za`.

Also, depends on your use case, but with `7za` there was no need to explicitly specify the encoding — unlike `unzip`, it managed to infer the correct encoding.

Comment: This won't work if the archive is created with some windows code page, there's no way for `7z` (`p7z` on linux/unix) to specify the code page as `GB18030`.