# Zipfile character encoding challenge

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, japanese

*NOTE: This question is different from [decompress ZIP with given encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/872596/decompress-zip-with-given-encoding) because none of those solutions work, and I'm unsure if a properly-functioning unzip program can even retrieve the correct filename.*

There is a zip file with a Japanese character file name. `unzip` can specify character encodings, which usually works to retrieve correct filenames. (It isn't in the `man` or `info` page for unzip for my distribution, but it is in the executable's help output.)

But it doesn't work for some zip files, including this one. This is a collection of files for the animating program MikuMikuDance. Several files have a 'garbage' filename when used with `unzip -O sjis -l archive.zip`, or when decompressed with file-roller.

Another file in the archive refers to the garbage filenames, although it refers to the shift-JIS encoding of the name and not UTF8. It tries to load these files, so if they're named wrong, they can't load. The question here is whether the zip file is such that the correct filenames could be extracted by a different program, and whether they were named correctly on the uploader's system.

The desired filename is 'Figure_その他.fx' ("other" in Japanese). It appears to have two different representations in the zip file, one as "����" which is SJIS being interpreted as UTF8, and elsewhere as U+0082 and some Thai characters:

[image: grep binary file]
This second version is the output from unzip, with or without `-O sjis` option. There doesn't seem to be any way to convert this back to the original filename.

The original zip file can be downloaded [here](https://senseitag.deviantart.com/art/Thank-You-For-You-Project-Download-475955137) (25 MB), and its contents can be opened with the free program MikuMikuDance although the '.fx' file is used for MikuMikuEffect which requires several native libraries to run in Wine. But maybe someone can answer this without the zip file.

Do zip files store an alternate filename that is normally unused? Is backslashes being displayed as yen signs on Japanese computers related in any way to the filename not being used? If you take the string that shows up as 'Normalmap Effect\Skin\Figure_���̑�.fx' and pipe it to `iconv -f sjis -t utf8`, the output is 'Normalmap Effect¥Skin¥Figure_その他.fx'. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Local_file_header) talks about an 'extra field'; is this being used to store and retrieve the 'bad' filename?

Comment: There is no formal specification for the charset used to encode entries in a zip file.

Comment: It's definitely not a duplicate of that post. I mention the top answer to that question in the first paragraph. Another answer mentioned 7z's encoding selection; `for i in {1..3000}; do  7z l -scs$i 'archive.zip' |grep その他; echo $i; done` returns nothing for i<3000, though there are a bunch of identifiers above 3000.

Comment: I get the same negative result for another zip file that does have filenames that are recognized by `unzip -O sjis -l archive.zip` though, so I'm doing it wrong or it's broken. (And grep <value>; echo $i changed to &&.)

Comment: Zip files _do_ sometimes have a separate field for "Unicode filename" (InfoZip style).

Comment: So the compressing program interpreted SJIS as iso8859-11 or something very similar, one of the bytes was somehow changed in the process, this wrong result was stored as "Unicode filename", and decompressing programs use the wrong result. The correct 'wrong' filename as iso8859-11 would be "<U+0082>ป<U+0082>ฬ<U+0091>ผ", but in the zipfile it's "Figure_<U+0082>ป<U+0082>ฬ‘ผ.fx".

Comment: Getting off topic, but how did SJIS > iso8859-11 (or maybe TIS-620) happen? Did packaging program assume the input was in the system encoding, which was Thai? This assumption was wrong because Thai encoding doesn't have Japanese characters; was the Japanese filename stored on disk as SJIS, or did the operating system read a UTF8 filename from disk, convert it to SJIS in memory for access by programs, and pass the SJIS sequence of bytes to the packaging program? The program that uses the file only loads it automatically in Linux/Wine if LANG variable set to ja_JP.UTF8; similar for Windows?

Answer (score 3):

I have just tested this for myself, using the link you provided, and downloaded a file entitled *Thank You For You Project.zip*, which I had to unzip using passcode **864** with 7-zip, and encountered no problems at all. Did I have the right file?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77060/discussion-on-answer-by-y-treehugger-cymru-zipfile-character-encoding-challenge).

Answer (score 1):

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
Backslashes displaying as yen signs is unrelated. The second filename is the UTF-8 filename, as documented in sections 4.5, 4.6, and Appendix D of the [.ZIP specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

In this particular case, the filename was passed to the packaging program in Shift-JIS, but was assumed to be ISO-8859-11 or TIS-620 (Thai encodings) by the packaging program. One of the bytes of the input was assumed to be, or converted into a different character in Unicode, preventing recovery of the correct filename.

When the Info-ZIP Unicode Path Extra Field is used, programs like 7z or Info-ZIP's `unzip` assume that it's valid, and ignore the basic filename field and the `-O` option used with `unzip` to set the source character encoding.

A patch that adds an option to override this behaviour would likely be welcomed by the program's maintainers.

UPDATED ANSWER:
-UU lets you ignore the Unicode filename. I don't know when this option was added. So,

```
 unzip -UU -O cp932 -l "Thank You For You Project.zip"
```

shows the original, Japanese-language filename: Figure_その他.fx.

Answer (score 1):

This issue with zips has been [fixed](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l/commit/73a19074dbe81fd25913dc5282825cb2ca9f8ceb) in the most recent [far2l file and archive manager](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l). For zip legacy charset detection by far2l to work properly, your system language setting should match the one set on the system where the archive was created (Windows' internal "zip folders" tool uses just the same logic). Also you can do

```
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 far2l
```