# How to decompress an encrypted zip file with ANSI encoded password?

Tags: linux, character-encoding, unzip

I need to decompress zip files generated in Windows with Japanese language. I'm using `unzip`.

If I use `unzip files.zip` I will get bad file names. So, according to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/872596/decompress-zip-with-given-encoding), I used `unzip` with `-O cp932` to decompress them. In this way, I can get correct file names.

However, some of these zip files require passwords. I know the correct passwords, but `unzip` always tells me the passwords are wrong.

After some investigation, I found out I can successfully decompress zip files with pure English passwords. That is, zip files with password like "Hello" will work, but a password like "こんにちは" leads to "wrong password". So I guess it has something to do with character encoding.

Actually, I tried both of these:

1. `unzip -O cp932 compressed.zip` and pasted "こんにちは" when it asked for password.
2. `unzip -O cp932 -P 'こんにちは' compressed.zip`.

None of them work.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369324/script-to-extract-a-zip-password-in-full-ascii-with-control-characters-0-31-ran) which has no answer. It looks like that question was asking for a way to provide any byte sequence to `unzip` as the password. If that question has an answer, then the solution would also apply to my question, since I can manually convert the passwords into correct character encoding, and give the converted string to `unzip`.

Comment: I would try other zip programs or a different terminal emulator

Comment: @golimar You can recommend other zip programs of course! As long as it solves this problem.

Comment: 7z or bsdtar also read zip files

Comment: @golimar I know. But do they support decompressing zip files with "cp932" encoded file names and passwords?

Comment: @RabidBear Not if you're talking about p7z which is the port of 7z running on Linux, it doesn't. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252000/421531). But I've found a solution for this, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

If a zip file is created with a non unicode codec and also encrypted with a password, the password you pass to `unzip` command also needs to be encoded as bytes in this specific codec. On Linux, the argument you pass to `unzip` will be read as `utf-8`, this is why `unzip -O cp932 -P 'こんにちは' compressed.zip` doesn't work.

So to sum it up, you need a way to provide password encoded with `cp932` as bytes to unzip. There's no simple way to do this with `unzip` command , but this can be done with a Python script:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile


def extract_zip(archive_name, out_path, pwd, codec):
    # password also needs to be encoded with codec
    password = pwd.encode(codec) if pwd else None
    # metadata_encoding argument is available in Python3.11
    with ZipFile(archive_name, "r", metadata_encoding=codec) as myzip:
        myzip.extractall(out_path, pwd=password)


extract_zip("compressed.zip", "output_dir", "こんにちは", "cp932")
```

Comment: The problem with Python `zipfile` module is that it only supports some of the compression formats but not all of them. For other formats it just raise an exception. So it is unlikely to be a general solution for all zip files. `zipfile` only supports "zipfile.ZIP_STORED", "zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED", "zipfile.ZIP_BZIP2" and "zipfile.ZIP_LZMA"

Comment: Oh another problem with `zipfile` is, even for supported formats, it is super slow to extract anything. Maybe it is not designed for extracting large zip files ...

Comment: @RabidBear `zipfile` module supports DEFLATED and several other compression methods, which are the most commonly used  methods and what most OS natively support, so it can handle most  use cases .As for the low speed, It's because the decrypting algorithm is written in pure Python, there's a CPython implementation if you want to check it out: https://github.com/V-E-O/czipfile.

Answer (score 0):

`zipfile` does not support AES-encrypted zip files at all, so it's out of picture.
A third party module [pyzipper](https://pypi.org/project/pyzipper/) does work with AES zip file, regardless compression algorithm. but it was created based on `zipfile` in Python 3.7, so it has no `metadata_encoding`. One can modify its source code to add that feature (fairly trivially), but here is a short script to just fix the filenames in post processing:

```python
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


import pyzipper


def extract_encrypted_ANSI_zip(zipfile, password, encoding='gbk', create_new_folder=True):
    zipfile = Path(zipfile)

    output_dir = Path.cwd() / zipfile.stem if create_new_folder else Path.cwd()

    # create a temp folder to extract into, so we can fix the filenames before moving them to the output folder
    temp = Path('temp')
    while temp.exists():
        temp = temp.with_name(temp.stem + '_')

    temp.mkdir()

    with pyzipper.AESZipFile(str(zipfile), 'r', compression=pyzipper.ZIP_DEFLATED, encryption=pyzipper.WZ_AES) as extracted_zip:
        extracted_zip.extractall(str(temp), pwd=password.encode(encoding, errors='replace'))

    all_files = [f for f in temp.rglob('*') if f.is_file()]
    for f in all_files:
        relative_path = f.relative_to(temp)
        old_path = str(relative_path)
        new_path = old_path.encode('cp437', errors='replace').decode(encoding, errors='replace')
        if new_path != old_path:
            print(old_path, '-->', new_path)

        f2 = (output_dir / new_path)
        f2.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        try:
            f.rename(f2)
        except FileExistsError:
            print(f2, 'already exists')

    shutil.rmtree(temp)

extract_encrypted_ANSI_zip('comparessed.zip', password="こんにちは", encoding='cp932')
```